# What is なって in 本物っぽいなって

Tags: meaning, anime

At the beginning of the movie "Your Name", there is a scene where Taki is waking up in Mitsuha's body, and comments "すげー本物っぽいなって".

What is the meaning of なって in this phrase?

Is this supposed to be て-form of なる, and he is commenting "they became like the real thing"?

Or is it some informal なあ..って that just describes his wonderment?
Or yet something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a sentence-end な followed by a quotative-って.

> すげー本物っぽいなって
>   (I was thinking) this looks so real.

Without this って (and the implied verb 思ってた), this sentence doesn't work as a response to her(his?) sister.

なる ("to become") is not relevant because なる **must** be preceded by the ku-form (連用形) of an adjective (or adjective-like auxiliary).

Answer (score 0):

> What is the meaning of なって in this phrase?
>
> Is this supposed to be て-form of なる, and he is commenting "they became like the real thing"?

It might be but seems unlikely without some kind of break like a comma (、) or a space between the っぽい and the なって. However, usually if it was なる then it would be っぽくなって not っぽいなって.

> Or is it some informal なあ..って that just describes his wonderment?

That would be my guess without any more context, although again it's difficult to guess what the って is doing there.

> Or yet something else?

I can't think of another alternative.