# Help understanding 自分自身すらも朱莉に乗せる判断をした?

Tags: word-usage

> 桐葉「いいわよ。ここまで来たらやってやろうじゃないの」
>
> 恐らく、以前のままならば彼女は否定していただろう。
>
> でも、長い間朱莉のことを考え、どうすればよい演技ができるのか、何が自分に足りないかを自問自答し続けた。
>
> それでも違うと否定され、藁をもすがる思いで**自分自身すらも朱莉に乗せる判断をした**。
>
> ……なんというか、大人らしい回りくどいやり方をする**な**と思いますよ、先生。

Context: 月見坂桐葉 works as a 声優 who has recently dubbed for a heroine named 朱莉 in an anime. But her performance has been criticized by her teacher called 姫子, who is the author of a light novel from which the anime is adapted. The protagnist 寿季 is helping 桐葉 understand the act of 朱莉 in the novel. And, after reaching his conclusion, 寿季 arranges to meet 姫子 somewhere at the school to check his answer with the teacher.

Could you translate the bold part? I'm not sure how I should understand it, especially the 乗せる. (桐葉 decided to overlap 朱莉?)

And what is the subject of 大人らしい回りくどいやり方をする? Is it 先生? The な doesn't mean "don't", right?

[image]

Comment: Related (for な): [What is なって in 本物っぽいなって](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76632/43676)

Comment: What is the thing she says she will do in the first line?

Comment: @aguijonazo The protagonist 寿季 tells her to act 朱莉 by "overlapping" without losing her (桐葉) own personality. And 桐葉 followed his instruction and rehearse her part again. I will attach a picture to make the context clearer.

Comment: 自分自身 is the object of 乗せる and 朱莉, marked with に, is the target toward which that action is directed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A literal translation is "to put/load even herself (桐葉) onto 朱莉", and this is basically just a paraphrase of キャラクターに自分を重ね合わせる (although キャラクターに自分を乗せる sounds less common to me). As an actress, 桐葉 may be able to put something like energy/emotion/spirit into the voice of 朱莉, but 寿季 and 先生 are thinking that's not enough. The point is that 桐葉 should not hide the existence of herself even when she is playing the role of someone else. The audience should be able to always feel not only 朱莉 but also 桐葉.

That な doesn't mean "don't". It's a friend of よ/ね/わ.